# How to find out IP address of a website, When it is hosted on cloudflare (Using Linux script or any other way)

Tags: shell-script, networking, ip

I want to find out the IP address of a website, which is using cloudflare for delivery. Using Linux shell script or some method in Linux.

Already one question was asked and it was closed with out answer. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55961/how-to-find-out-the-hosting-provider-of-a-website-protected-with-cloudflare

I hope to get answer here.

Comment: You mean you want the IP of the host **behind** the CDN? Short answer: you can't.

Comment: This is also not a question about unix or linux. Since webmasters rejected it as well, I might recommend serverfault, or superuser (be sure to read their on-topic policy first).

Comment: Whilst actually there are scripts for Linux, I agree this is off-topic and more suited for https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro not sure security.SE will take it as written. I suspect SF would reject too, but it might get accepted on SU.

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:* you cannot find the IP address(es) of host(s) behind Cloudflare addresses.

*Long answer:* some misconfigurations or web site vulnerabilities my expose the true IP address(es) of (some) websites behind Cloudfare.

See for instance, an automated tool to find some common misconfigurations, [CFire](https://rhinosecuritylabs.com/cloud-security/cloudflare-bypassing-cloud-security/)

From Rhino Security Labs - CFire page

> To summarize:
>
> - CloudFlare is a great cloud security tool, offering WAF/DDoS
>     protection by hosting your DNS and protecting the true IP of your
>     domains
> - CloudFlare requires proper configuration and maintenance to be its
>     most effective
> - Server IPs may still be exposed if moved to CloudFlare from “direct
>     IP” DNS provider
> - Subdomains bypassing CloudFlare often exposes all DNS records to
>     bypass attacks